# Accuracy of numbers provided by the "Statistics Advanced" module?

Tags: 6, nodes, google-analytics

We use modules [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) and [Statistics Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced), in Drupal 6. It is clear from the numbers that they provide very different readings.

Can anyone give any accuracy analysis for the [Statistics Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced) module, perhaps by comparison with Google?

Answer (score 0):

As it relates to [Statistics Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced), you may want to take into account some of the options mentioned on its project page. Such as:

> Only track 'unique' views of content: If you keep viewing a node over and over again, the "x reads" counter won't increase each time. This is applied on a per-user basis as well as a per session id for anonymous users.

Refer to the project page for other options mentioned there.

<sup>Disclosure: I'm the (new) maintainer of [Statistics Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced).</sup>